# Henotheism in the Puranas?

Tags: puranas, bhakti

The henotheism, a kind of halfway house between polytheism and monotheism reflects the demotion of the many gods of the Hindu pantheon to the position of portions (amsas) of one primary God.

This concept is frequently found in bhakti literature, particularly in the Puranas.

Which passages best represent it?

Comment: First, my readings of henotheism from Max Mueller and commentaries by Prof.  Surendranath Dasgupta and Prof Chandradhar Sharma would lead me to a different understanding as to what henotheism is. It is a theory originally put forward by Max Mueller in the 19th century and is of the nature of an anthropological question rather than a religious or philosophical theory. It was never accepted as a valid theological or philosophical interpretation.

Comment: The meaning for this question must be referred just with its definition  : Friedrich Schelling coined the term henotheism, from the Greek heis or heno which literally means "single, one".[1][2][6] The term refers to a form of theism focused on a single god.